# how to join 5 tabes of a database using subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The question is "Write a query to show all the **employees**:

`last_name`, `first_name`, `phone_number`, `department_name`, `city`, `country`, and `region`. Sort by `last_name` and then by `first_name`.

The problem is fields are in 5 different tables of database

[image]

I tried but don't know how to wire it further

```
use hr;

SELECT first_name
     , last_name
     , PHONE_NUMBER
     , ( SELECT department_name
          FROM departments d 
         where e.department_id = d.department_id) department 
  FROM employees e 
 ORDER 
    BY last_name;
```

Comment: Ok, so our questions is: ... where is the query that shows your attempt to solve the problem? ... This is not a write-4-U coding site.

Comment: HINT: you don’t need a subquery, you need to JOIN the tables eg start with employees table then JOIN jobs table based on job_id, then JOIN another table and so on until all the fields you need are available. Look up how to do JOINs - and the different types.

Comment: Why would you want a subquery here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need *subquery*. You can do that by  using `LEFT JOIN` query:

> *The **`LEFT JOIN`** keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.* [1](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

[image: LEFT JOIN]

**Code Syntax**

```
SELECT employees.first_name, employees.last_name,
    departments.department_name, locations.city,
    countries.country_name, regions.region_name
FROM employees

LEFT JOIN departments ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id,

LEFT JOIN locations ON departments.location_id = locations.location_id,

LEFT JOIN countries ON locations.country_id = countries.country_id,

LEFT JOIN regions ON locations.region_id = regions.region_id

ORDER BY employees.last_name, employees.first_name;
```

---

You can also use `INNER JOIN` if you want the common values from both tables.

> *The **`INNER JOIN`** keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables.* [2](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

[image: INNER JOIN]

**Code Syntax**

```
SELECT employees.first_name, employees.last_name,
    departments.department_name, locations.city,
    countries.country_name, regions.region_name
FROM employees

INNER JOIN departments ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id,

INNER JOIN locations ON departments.location_id = locations.location_id,

INNER JOIN countries ON locations.country_id = countries.country_id,

INNER JOIN regions ON locations.region_id = regions.region_id

ORDER BY employees.last_name, employees.first_name;
```